# All Documents View, how to go back up the heirarchy with one click

Tags: navigation, libraries

I'm working a lot right now in **`All Documents`** view, but am frustrated with wanting to hit one icon, like windows explorer or all browsers have to go back 'up the chain'.

Is there a way to enable this for my SharePoint site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly wht you want but here it goes.  In SP 2007, you have the site level breadcrumbs which allow you to go "up the chain" at the folder / list level all the way up to the current site.  You also have the global breadcrumbs at the top that allow you to go "up the chain" to parent sites in the current site collection.

Comment: I think he uses the library with an list web part on a normal page. There he has no breadcrumb for the library/list and no option to get one step back.

Comment: OK, I see the lines you're talking about and I guess they'll work, just a break with the standards used elsewhere.  Thanks.